# Task Manager, ProcessExplorer, or similar tool: monitoring and managing CLR threads

Tags: .net, performance, monitoring

Is there a tool out there that allows to see managed threads as they are running in CLR?  Ideally, I would like to see CPU load, state, managed name, and managed id, hopefully even if the thread belongs to thread pool, or is a background thread.  It would be able to have ability to group/collapse thread pools, foreground threads, and background threads.

Motivation:

I am using CLR Profiler for dev work. I was hoping for the simplicity of Process Explorer, so that it can be used by testers and customer support, even just running in the background.

Comment: Hi , @Gregc , I have the same problem as you faced before , I want to monitor the thread created in my application, at least I want to know the thread's state such as dead or alive.If you can share your solution with me or give me a direction , I will be appreciated it . thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang If this is new code you're writing, I would highly recommend ditching threads and using tasks.  TPL directly supports what you're looking for.  If this is some code you've inherited from before, consider asking a good question and providing a link so I can take a stab at answering it.

Comment: Hi , @Gregc ,Actually I am going to write this code for my application. Could you give me more detail about it . Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Joe.wang here's a good read: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Thanks, This article tells about the threading mechanism and thread safety etc. Any others for threading monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency Visualizer was able to provide the insights I needed.

Answer (score 1):

[CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1) should work for what you're looking for.

Comment: I was using CLRProfiler 2.0.  +1 for the link to updated version.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been using [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx)?  [Here's a decent blog post](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/30/perfmon-your-debugging-buddy/) about it and some details about many of the counters available for monitoring .NET during runtime.

Comment: +1 for the nice link.  The blog seems relevant, but the actual post does not point out what I'm looking for.  These features are also a part of Process Explorer, btw.  I am looking for a breakdow similar to the threads tab within Process Explorer, but over managed threads.

Comment: @GregC: I don't believe it does, sorry.

Comment: I am developing a feeling that this question might need a bounty...  This is so fundamental, somebody has got to make one :)