# How to enumerate running processes managed by CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, process, appdomain

How to enumerate running processes?  What about app domains?

Would there be any security-related gotchas?

I would be comfortable with .NET 4.0 only, Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2-only solution.

P.S.: This is what I am trying to do...
[ProcessExplorer.NET question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720023/task-manager-processexplorer-or-similar-tool-monitoring-and-managing-clr-threa)

Comment: Having not tried this myself, you can programmatically access the various [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (like what perfmon shows), and from those, use the counters that deal with CLR like `.NET CLR Loading | Current appdomains`

Comment: Here's what i am looking at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat.aspx

Comment: Would WMI be relevant here?  Is there a more refactoring-friendly and type-safe way to do this?

Comment: Looking at the docs, I get the impression that `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` and `System.Management.Instrumentation` will both give you the answers you're looking for, but the former's API is small subset of the latter's much richer API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) will list all the running processes as [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
[Examine Running Processes Using Both Managed and Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163900.aspx)

Comment: The link seems dated.  It does not address my concerns for Win7 security.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use Process.GetProcesses above, you can use ICLRMetaHost::EnumerateLoadedRuntimes to see if the process is running an instance of the CLR, and get the versions of the CLR running in it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233119.aspx.  The API isn't exposed to .NET directly, but it's COM so you can tlbimport mscoree.dll and use the autogenerated wrappers in .NET.

Comment: By looking at the docs, this seems to be a reasonable path to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
         foreach (Process proc in procs)
         {
            string processName = proc.ProcessName;
            int processId = proc.Id;

            try
            {
               if (proc.HasDesktop40CLR())
                  Console.WriteLine("#{0}, {1} (has Desktop CLR 4.0+)", processId, processName);

               if (proc.HasOlderDesktopCLR())
                  Console.WriteLine("#{0}, {1} (has Older Desktop CLR)", processId, processName);

               if (proc.HasMscorlib())
                  Console.WriteLine("#{0}, {1} (has MSCORLib)", processId, processName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("#{0}, {1} (skipped/unknown)", processId, processName);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public static class ProcessExtensions
   {
      public static bool HasDesktop40CLR(this Process proc)
      {
         for (int ix = 0; ix < proc.Modules.Count; ++ix)
         {
            var moduleName = proc.Modules[ix].ModuleName;

            if (string.Compare(moduleName, "mscoree.dll", ignoreCase: true) == 0)
               return true;

            if (string.Compare(moduleName, "mscoreei.dll", ignoreCase: true) == 0)
               return true;
         }

         return false;
      }

      public static bool HasOlderDesktopCLR(this Process proc)
      {
         for (int ix = 0; ix < proc.Modules.Count; ++ix)
         {
            var moduleName = proc.Modules[ix].ModuleName;

            if (string.Compare(moduleName, "mscorwks.dll", ignoreCase: true) == 0)
               return true;
         }

         return false;
      }

      public static bool HasMscorlib(this Process proc)
      {
         for (int ix = 0; ix < proc.Modules.Count; ++ix)
         {
            var moduleName = proc.Modules[ix].ModuleName;

            if (string.Compare(moduleName, "mscorlib.dll", ignoreCase: true) == 0)
               return true;

            if (string.Compare(moduleName, "mscorlib.ni.dll", ignoreCase: true) == 0)
               return true;
         }

         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, thank you!  I have edited the reply to add a few important conditions the code must meet.